# Get a category name or link from Magento CMS

Tags: php, magento

I have a home cms page with an imagemap on it and I would like to the link to the href tags for the category on the images, also when I roll over the links I would like to display the name of the category. I can do all of this by hard coding it. but would like to to be a bit more dynamic. I have search around I could seem to find a way to get a catalog name and link as a CMS.

can I do something like

```
<area id="item1" shape="rect" coords="237,12,426,323" href="{{store link="category/3"}}" />

<div id="rollover">{{store name="category/3"}}"</div>
```

or does anyone know any good documentation on what you can do with Magento cms

Answer (score 0):

you can see it as below

```
<a href="{{config path="web/secure/base_url"}}men.html">
```

where men.html is your `URL key` from your category.

i would suggest you do not use static id of category

you can adjust with your convenience.

hope this will help to you.